# C++ convert fixed-size file of integers to 2d array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, file, int

I am working on a simple grid-based console game, and I want to read from a saved file full of IDs. The file looks somewhat like this (the actual file is wider and taller):

```
0101
4057
5432
5145
```

Each int is one digit, this would be read as an array of size [4][4] for example. In this case, the size is defined by const int dimX and dimY. The actual files are 48x24. When the grid is drawn, it already uses a 2D array of IDs to do so, so a workaround of that nature is not possible.

I currently have this code (please forgive my namespace std):

```
void loadBoard(string filename, boardType board)
{
    filename.append("." + board.extension);
    ifstream ifs(filename);
}
```

It will be read into `int tileIDArray[dimY][dimX]` but is later converted to `tile g.board.board[dimY][dimX]`.
Thanks!